# Exporting code from locales with multiple parameters

Tags: isabelle

according to the [codegen](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/codegen.pdf) documentation section "7.3 Locales and interpretation", exporting code from locales is a bit tricky but achievable. The following example works fine:

```
locale localTest =
  fixes A :: "string"
begin
  fun concatA :: "string ⇒ string" where "concatA x = x@A"
  definition concatAA :: "string ⇒ string" where "concatAA x = x@A@A"
end

definition localtest_concatA :: "string ⇒ string " where
[code del]: "localtest_concatA = localTest.concatA ''a''"
definition localtest_concatAA :: "string ⇒ string " where
[code del]: "localtest_concatAA = localTest.concatAA ''a''"

interpretation localTest "''a''"
  where "localTest.concatA ''a'' = localtest_concatA"
  and "localTest.concatAA ''a'' = localtest_concatAA"
  apply unfold_locales
  apply(simp_all add: localtest_concatA_def localtest_concatAA_def)
  done

export_code localtest_concatA localtest_concatAA in Scala file -
```

How can I export code for locales with multiple parameters? Given the following `locale`:

```
locale localTest =
  fixes A :: "string"
  fixes B :: "string"
begin
  fun concatA :: "string ⇒ string" where "concatA x = x@A"
  definition concatB :: "string ⇒ string" where "concatB x = x@B"
end
```

I can interpret it with

```
interpretation localTest "''a''" "''b''" .
```

But I canot use this interpretation in a definition

```
definition localtest_concatA :: "string ⇒ string " where
[code del]: "localtest_concatA = localTest.concatA ''a'' ''b''"
```

It fails with

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ list" and "_ ⇒ _"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  op = localtest_concatA :: (char list ⇒ char list) ⇒ bool
Operand:   localTest.concatA ''a'' ''b'' :: char list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your introduced constants, e.g., by the `term` command. We have

```
term localTest.concatA
```

with output

```
"localTest.concatA" :: "char list ⇒ char list ⇒ char list"
```

You see that in addition to the single parameter that you gave in the original definition (inside the locale), there is an additional one (but only 1 not 2, since the definition does not rely on `B`).

Now, after your interpretation (since you did not explicitly provide a name, the constants of `localTest` will be in scope without qualifier) we have

```
term concatA
```

with output

```
"localTest.concatA ''a''" :: "char list ⇒ char list"
```

That is, `localTest.concatA ''a''` is already of type `string => string`. You additionally add `''b''` and obtain type `string`, but your type annotation says `string => string`. So there is really a clash of types and the reason was that you gave too many arguments to `localTest.concatA`. Try using

```
definition localtest_concatA :: "string ⇒ string " where
  [code del]: "localtest_concatA = concatA
```

instead.